# php if counter is equal to x or y

Tags: php, if-statement, counter

I want to arrange my WP post with one full-width post at the top of the page and then 3 posts per row.

I have everything displaying, but what I'm left with is 3 if statements before and after my columns. I'm sure this is really simple, but when I tried using "if ( $counter == 1 | 4 | 7 )" I got a row for every div. Is there a more concise way to write this and get the same outcome?

```
<?php if <?php if ( $counter == 1 ) : ?>: ?>

    <div class="row"><!-- .row - 1 -->

<?php elseif ( $counter == 4 ) : ?>

    <div class="row"><!-- .row  - 4-->

<?php elseif ( $counter == 7 ) : ?>

    <div class="row">   <!-- .row  - 7 -->  

<?php endif; ?> 

        <div class="col-md-4">

         <p>Content</p>

        </div>


<?php if ( $counter == 3 ) : ?>

        </div><!-- .row 3 -->

<?php elseif ( $counter == 6 ) : ?>

        </div><!-- .row 6 -->

<?php elseif ( $counter == 9 ) : ?>

        </div><!-- .row 9 -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `if ( $counter == 1 || $counter == 4 || $counter == 7 )`

Comment: You can perhaps use the modulus operator, `if ($counter % 3 == 1)` for the first, and equal to zero on the latter.

Comment: Hopefully the first line is a copy/paste error otherwise you need to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to use in_array (especially if the options are random and there are many of them)

```
if (in_array($counter, [1, 4, 7]))
```

Also be careful that the single | symbol is a bitwise operator. Learn more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using modulo so you dont have to write a condition for each 3. Something like:

```
if ($counter % 3 == 0)
```

will match any time the counter is a multiple of 3, and you can change the number to match whatever condition you want.

Comment: I had tried this, but it broke the layout. I think because I already had a full width column above.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple statements in php are written as separate cases. i.e.

```
if ( $counter == 1 || $counter == 4 || $counter == 7 )
```

But in your case, using modulo operator, which returns **the modulo** (remainder of division), it can be simplified to:

```
if ( $counter%3 == 1 ) {
    // Open div
}

if ( $counter%3 == 0 ) {
    // Close div
}
```